# A better way of writing this script so it does not return an aggregate error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This script gives me an aggregate error because of the presence of t3.Date.
Is there another way of writing this please?

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Date, t2.Type, t1.Username
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.CareID = t2.CareID AND 
t1.Date = t2.Date AND
t1.Username = t2.Username
LEFT JOIN t3
ON t1.CareID = t3.CareID AND t1.Username = t3.Username
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.Date, t2.Type, t1.Username
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND t1.Date <= t3.Date
```

Comment: HAVING COUNT(*) specify table alias and you haven't apply group by for t3, so can't use in having close

Comment: @SandipPatel Sorry but could you please expand on that or paste in an example? Thank you

Comment: It depends on what is "this".  May be t1.date< min(t3.date) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the below script.

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Date, t2.Type, t1.Username
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.CareID = t2.CareID AND 
t1.Date = t2.Date AND
t1.Username = t2.Username
LEFT JOIN t3
ON t1.CareID = t3.CareID AND t1.Username = t3.Username AND t1.Date <= t3.Date
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.Date, t2.Type, t1.Username
HAVING COUNT(t1.ID) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove:

```
 AND t1.Date <= t3.Date
```

from the `HAVING` clause and place it in the `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
...
LEFT JOIN t3
ON t1.CareID = t3.CareID AND t1.Username = t3.Username AND t1.Date <= t3.Date
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.Date, t2.Type, t1.Username
...
```

Answer (score 1):

your Having statement miss alias name, so write like `Count(t1.Id)` and also remove `AND t1.Date <= t3.Date` from having and put in join statement

```
SELECT 
    t1.ID, 
    t1.Date, 
    t2.Type, 
    t1.Username
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.CareID = t2.CareID 
    AND t1.Date = t2.Date 
    AND t1.Username = t2.Username
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t1.CareID = t3.CareID 
    AND t1.Username = t3.Username
    AND t1.Date <= t3.Date
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.Date, t2.Type, t1.Username
HAVING COUNT(t1.ID) = 1
```